# How to use ng-src for IFRAME with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat "data in datas">
<iframe ng-src="myurl.html?cat={{data.id}}">
```

By the way it's just a local file no cross domain problem.

I know how to do with fixed url using $sce but don't know how with variable url which varies with ng-repeat

Comment: Looks like you might have a typo on `ng-repeat` is missing and equal.

Comment: did you inject sanitize module?.. give correct path. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-repeat should be,

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {    
     $scope.datas = [{ id: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg" },
{ id: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8455/8048926748_1bc624e5c9_d.jpg" }];
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="data in datas">
      <a href='#'><img ng-src="myurl.html?cat={{data.id}}" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my problem is not ng-repeat but ng-src for iframe: {{data.id}} within ng-src doesn't work

Comment: check the sample above, you can check whether its binded or not by opening the link in new tab

Comment: Hi sorry, in my title I didn't mention it was with an iframe, it was only in my code so I changed the title.

Comment: you can do the same, demo is here :http://plnkr.co/edit/aXDc2nILTa3M1Z6wu4PD?p=preview